# Can ASP.NET core dependency injection inject null references?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

In my job we are developing ASP.NET core applications. I keep seeing the follwing pattern used with dependency injection. In this example `Logic` depends on `OtherLogic`:

```cs
public class Logic {
    private readonly OtherLogic myOtherLogic;

    public Logic(OtherLogic myOtherLogic) {
        // I mean specifically this pattern of checking injected dependencies for null:
        this.myOtherLogic = myOtherLogic
            ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(myOtherLogic));
    }
}
```

All dependencies are added to an `IServiceCollection` during service configuration and both (`Logic` and `OtherLogic`) are only retrieved from dependency injection. In my current project I'm using .Net 5 and I have enabled nullable reference types if that matters.

I'd like to drop this Guard Clause pattern, because I believe the injector will always throw an exception (during service configuration) when it's unable to resolve a non-optional service.
My question is, in which circumstances the injector could inject a null-reference for a non-optional service? Is it even possible?

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection) doesn't mention the possibility of null being injected, but as far as I can see, also doesn't explicitly deny it. Just want to make sure I don't run into trouble later on, thanks for your time :)

Comment: The .NET 5's DI will take care of you so I don't this it is possible to inject null. However, when you did not Add that required service in Program.cs (.NET 6)/startup.cs(.NET5 and prior) then it will throw exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under 'normal' conditions (i.e. when solely depending on the use of Auto-Wiring) `null` values can't be injected.

> ***DEFINITION**: Auto-Wiring is the ability to automatically compose an object graph from maps between Abstractions and concrete types by making use of type information supplied by the compiler and the Common Language Runtime (CLR).*

The following code snippets, however, show examples of when `null` references can be injected into `Logic`:

#### Case 1: Manual construction

```cs
new Logic(null);
```

It's always possible to create instances outside the context of the DI Container by manually invoking its constructor using plain-old C#. In most cases you wouldn't inject `null` directly, but there could be many reasons why this happens, for instance by calling a method to retrieve the dependency, while this method has a default case where null is returned, or when the dependency comes from a static field that wasn't initialized yet, which can happen if static fields have a dependency upon each other.

#### Case 2: Direct null injection through factory registration

```cs
services.AddTransient(c => new Logic(null));
```

This case is practically identical to case 1, but now you wrap the creation inside the factory delegate of a registration.

#### Case 3: Incorrect use of `GetService` opposed to `GetRequiredService` in factory

```cs
services.AddTransient(c => new Logic(c.GetService<OtherLogic>()));
```

The MS.DI container contains a `GetService<T>` method that allows retrieving the dependency, but returns `null` in case the registration for `T` does not exist. A misconfiguration could, therefore, allow `null` to be injected. Instead, you should almost always call the `GetRequiredService<T>` extension method, which ensures and exception is thrown and `null` is never returned. `GetRequiredService<T>` even throws an exception when the dependency *is* registered, but its factory delegate returns `null`, as can be seen in the next case.

#### Case 4: Auto-registration with dependency that returns `null` from its factory registration

```cs
services.AddTransient<Logic>();
services.AddTransient<OtherLogic>(c => null);
```

In this case a factory registration is made that directly or (more commonly) indirectly a `null` reference. MS.DI allows that `null` reference of `OtherLogic` to be injected into `Logic`.

In my opinion, option 4 should not be allowed, and I consider it a design flaw in MS.DI to allow a factory registration to return `null`. But that still leaves the other three cases where the `Logic` constructor is called using plain-old C#.

Whether or not you want to be very safe and protect the class's pre conditions using a Guard Clause is up to you. Personally, for applications where I make use of a DI Container that doesn't allow case 4 and makes it hard to do case 3, I typically leave out the Guard Clauses. This even allows me to use the more concise `record` syntax:

```cs
// WARNING: No null checks are performed in the record constructor
public sealed record Logic(OtherLogic MyOtherLogic)
{
}
```

As a counter argument, though, its worth to mention that the addition of these null check Guard Clauses would not result in any maintainability issues, as they don't change after being written. They are part of the class's DI infrastructure, and although a bit noisy, won't cause sweeping changes in the long run.

You could also argue that it's not up to the class to 'know' whether it is constructed using a DI Container or using [Pure DI](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/). This means that the class should itself check its invariants and prevent it to be initialized in an invalid state.

So there are multiple ways to look at this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It should not be necessary to check parameters being passed into the constructor  with dependency injection as (like you mentioned) exceptions will occur when registering the dependency as you mentioned.

I found an article here on this topic where someone suggests that future implementations of DI could results in null injections: https://stevetalkscode.co.uk/null-injection

However, the article is hypothetical and the scenarios are quite specific. I think it's okay to get rid of the null checks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer & link, good read.

Answer (score 0):

The modern way to achieve this is to simply not register the dependency you want to be `null` and then set your constructor parameter as nullable.

In an ASP.NET Core action you can do the following:

```
public IActionResult MyAction([FromServices] IMyNullableDepedency? dependency) {
  ...
}
```